# Facebooks email_hashes empty when querying with FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have an app which can invite a user's Facebook friends. I need to verify if the friends are already registered with my app. Facebook doesn't give friends' emails, so my idea was to get email hashes. I wanted to do this using FQL and email_hashes column from users table http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

> An array
>   containing a set of confirmed email hashes for the user. Emails are
>   registered via the deprecated connect.registerUsers API call and are
>   only confirmed when the user adds your application. The format of each
>   email hash is the crc32 and md5 hashes of the email address combined
>   with an underscore (_).

But when I test my query:

```
SELECT email_hashes FROM user WHERE uid = some_fb_id
```

..I get an empty array. Is Facebook not supporting email_hashes any more or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> I have an app which can invite a user's Facebook friends.

So you have at least their user ids?

> I need to verify if the friends are already registered with my app.

If you have their id, you can just look into the user object/table for the field `installed` (Graph API) resp. `is_app_user` (FQL).

> Is Facebook not supporting email_hashes any more or am I missing something?

I don’t know for sure, but I guess so. That whole concept seems to be deprecated.

Comment: Yes, I have the friends' ids. I think that this approach is similar to what I am doing at the background - when a user logs in with a Facebook account I save his uid. Then when a different user invites someone I search the saved uids. But this approach doesn't handle a situation when somebody has an account in my app but didn't log in with Facebook.